# controlar la ejecución de onkeyup utilizando una sentencia IF

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

```
<label>Documento</label>

      <select type="select" name="documento" id="tipo"class="form-control" >
          <?php

          $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vitae"); // Alternativa 1
          mysqli_query ($link,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
          $c=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM wp_tipo_documento order by id_tipo_documento");
          while($d=mysqli_fetch_array($c))
          {

              echo '<option value="'.$d['id_tipo_documento'].'" selected>'.$d['nombre_tipo_documento'].'</option>';
          }
          ?>
      </select>

      <br>
```

Documento de Identidad

Bien en el código anterior yo estoy llamando de la BD el tipo de documento legal con el cual se va a registrar el usuario ya sea pasaporte, la cédula, etc.

lo que necesito hacer es ejecutar una función de javascript utilizando onkeyup y esta ejecución va a depender del valor que se seleccione en el combobox, es posible controlar esta ejecución mediante un IF o algo similar. Es decir si seleccione uno se ejecuta si selecciona 2 no se ejecuta....

Comment: A que componente quieres condicionarle el evento keyup???

Comment: bien le quiero condicionar el evento keyup a un texbox :   <input type="text" id="cedula" name="cedula" onkeyup="validate(this.value)" autofocus placeholder="Ej: 8-123-456">, lo quiero en pocas palabras si elijo la opcion 1 se ejecute y si elijo la opcion2 no se ejecute

Answer (score 0):

Adjuntando la librería de JQuery puedes agregarle un listener keyup al html o cualquier elemento.

El keyCode puedes condicionarlo a cualquiera que necesites, para saber el keyCode del teclado puedes agregar console.log(e.keyCode); después del keyup

```
$('html').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        var option = document.getElementbyId('tipo').value;//Obtener valor en Javascript
        //var option = $('#tipo').val()//Obtener valor en JQuery
        if(option==1){
            //ejecuta
        }else{
            //No ejecuta
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

la respuesta es si, se puede poner un if al interno del keyup o cualquier otro evento.

si queres buscar en base al valor seleccionado tendrias que hacer lo siguiente :

```js
//utilizando JavaScript : 

   var select = document.getElementById("tipo");
   
   
   select.addEventListener("change", function(){
       if (select.value == "1"){
         console.log("seleccionaste la primera opcion");
       }else if (select.value == "2"){
         console.log("seleccionaste la segunda opcion");
       }else if (select.value == "3"){
         console.log("seleccionaste la tercera opcion");
       }
   });
   
   
   //utilizando jQuery 
   
   //opcion 1
   
   $("#tipo").on("change", function(e){
      if ($(this).val() == "1"){
         console.log("seleccionaste la primera opcion jQuery");
      }else if ($(this).val() == "2"){
         console.log("seleccionaste la segunda opcion jQuery");
      }else if ($(this).val() == "3"){
         console.log("seleccionaste la tercera opcion jQuery");
       }
   });
   
   //opcion 2
   $("#tipo").change(function(e){
      if ($(this).val() == "1"){
         console.log("seleccionaste la primera opcion jQuery2");
      }else if ($(this).val() == "2"){
         console.log("seleccionaste la segunda opcion jQuery2");
      }else if ($(this).val() == "3"){
         console.log("seleccionaste la tercera opcion jQuery2");
      }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="tipo">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

ya que, si no entendi mal, lo que estas tratando de hacer es ejecutar una funcion en base al dato seleccionado en el select.. el `keyup` no te va a servir. en este caso utilizaria el `change` como en el ejemplo, que al cambiar el valor seleccionado, hace saltar el evento.

si el elemento al cual le queres poner el listener es un input, ahi te diria que el `keyup` esta bien, lo unico que tenes que hacer es cambiar el `change` por el `keyup` (referencia al codigo anterior)

ejemplo con keyup :

```js
// JS 

var input = document.getElementById("ejemploKeyup");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
 
    console.log(this.value);
})

//jQuery 1 

$("#ejemploKeyup").on("keyup",function(){
      console.log($(this).val()+" jQuery");
})

//jQuery 2

$("#ejemploKeyup").keyup(function(){
      console.log($(this).val()+" jQuery2");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="ejemploKeyup">
```

espero que te sea de ayuda.